# AJAX errors in Safari only

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ajax, safari

Ah, Safari, how I <del>hate</del> <del>despise</del> *lo<del>ath</del>ve* you...

For an unknown reason I am trying to diagnose, users of my site are experiencing an issue in which AJAX requests are failing with status code 0 and error code "error". Very useful.

It's intermittent and from what we can tell only affects Safari.

AJAX requests are not cross-origin, all use domain-relative paths (eg. `/farm/notices`). jQuery is in use, and the code is passing through `xhr.fail()`.

I don't believe it's a network issue, as some cases included screenshots showing a full-strength WiFi signal.

I'm seriously at my wit's end with this. A lot of people use iPhones/iPads and Safari is literally the only option (even Chrome is more like Safari in disguise...) so it's quite a portion of users who are suffering from this issue.

So... any ideas? At all? Thanks ^^

EDIT: I have added a silent retry in this case, which should at least help mitigate the issue. If I'm not mistaken, an error like this means that the server hasn't seen the request yet, so a retry should be fine...

Comment: Hi there! What's at the other end of the ajax call? WordPress? PHP app? RoR? Any way we could have an API URL to test with?

Comment: PHP, no frameworks as it's a custom-built game. It's https://pokefarm.com/ - you can test using the frontpage "Interaction" area, or the login form.